# How to understand "completeness" intuitively?

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

In my text, it says, "if cauchy sequence in a normed vector space converge, i.e. $$\lim_{j,k \to\infty} ||u_j - u_k|| = 0$$ then the normed vector space is complete".

The definition of completeness confuses me. Should I view $u_j$ and $u_k$ as completely different functions? Or should I view them as different instances of the same function $u$?

Just to understand this from an applied perspective, does it simply mean that a function reaches a steady state at some point?

Comment: Question for you: in the space of rational numbers, can you give an example of a Cauchy sequence that does not converge (to a rational number)?

Answer (score 0):

$u_j$ and $u_k$ are elements of the normed vector space. If the vector space is for instance $C([0,1])$, the space of continuous functions on the interval $[0,1]$, twoexaples of sequences $\{u_k\}\subset X$ are
$$
\{\cos(k\,x)\}_{k=1}^\infty,\quad\Bigl\{\frac{k}{k+x}\Bigr\}_{k=1}^\infty
$$